# Adding textbox value into grid at runtime

Tags: c#

I have two textboxes and I want to display their value in a grid.
When I click on the Add button, I want to create a grid dynamically at runtime.  I also want to add the textbox values into the grid repeatedly when I want to display it.

Comment: I tried to clarify your question, but you should still try to add details about what you're trying to do and what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

ok... As per what you have said you want to create a dynamic grid and and you would like to add Values inside the textbox control inside the gridview? is my understanding is correct ?

check this link out : http://praveensunsetpoint.wordpress.com/2008/05/09/dynamic-gridvieweditdeleteinsertselect-just-copy-paste-and-enjoy-it/